# Timeout on opening and reading from a named pipe in Java

Tags: java, linux, scala, named-pipes, nonblocking

In my current design I have a named pipe which can be sequentially written to by an unspecified number of writer processes. There is only one reader implemented in Scala, but for the sake of simplicity we can assume it's implemented in Java. The operating system is Linux >= 2.6.

The reader needs to:

1. re-open the pipe after each writer sends its input
2. read all the input from pipe until EOF which indicates that the writer closed its end of the named pipe

The main difficulty here is that the reader needs to be able to cancel both open and read calls after a given timeout. Reaching the timeout indicates that all writers have done their job and the reader can safely exit.

In C, I would:

1. first call open(file_name, O_NONBLOCK) and poll for the pipe to be open for writing
2. poll for reading in non-blocking mode or change file descriptor to blocking mode and use select()

What is the most straightforward way to complete this in Java? I've looked at the classic IO and NIO but there more I try, the more complex the design becomes and it still doesn't do exactly what I want.

Comment: Not sure if you are accounting for it, but a timeout might occur if no writers ever used the pipe, not just after they are done.

Comment: That's actually why I'm asking this question: I haven't really found a way to do non-blocking open() in Java...